# cambiar el orden de lectura de los nodos html5 y css

Tags: html, css, css3

tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class"prim"> texto primero </div>

<div class"seg"> texto segundo </div>
```

quiero que cuando abra la página, el "texto segundo" aparezca primero,  como si estuviese colocado el primero.
Sé que existe una propiedad css para cambiarlo, pero no la recuerdo y tampoco la encuentro...

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
.prim{
//código CSS
}

.seg{
//código CSS
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes englobar ambos elementos dentro de un contenedor y asignarles la propiedad `display: flex`:

- Mediante la propiedad `flex-flow` le indicarás la orientación (row/column).
- Mediante la propiedad `order` indicarás el orden que van a llevar esos elementos dentro del contenedor teniendo en cuenta la propiedad `flex-flow` para posicionarse.

```css
#contenedor{
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
}

.prim{
   order: 2;
}

.seg{
   order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="prim"> texto primero </div>
  
  <div class="seg"> texto segundo </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.  Me he vuelto un poco loco porque la aplicación es grande y tengo ya mucha clases, pero  al final funciona.

Answer (score -4):

¿Intentaste con...?

```
.seg {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: No, no vi tu respuesta e hice lo que me dijo el primer compañero. Pero es  cierto que lo que tú dices me suena  más... Lo tendré en  cuenta para la próxima!!! Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaCano  el `z-index` lo que hace es establecer la prioridad en el eje z, pero no te va a cambiar el orden de los elementos. Simplemente unos se situarán por encima de otros en función de su prioridad, como si tuvieran profundidad (eje z).

Comment: No entiendo porque seleccionas esta respuesta como la correcta si lo has solucionado con la otra, además como dice @FranciscoRomero el `z-index` no hace lo que tú pides en la pregunta

Comment: Porque en función de cómo interpretes mi pregunta, puede valer una u otra. No solucionó mi duda, pero puede solucionar la de otra gente, por lo que es una respuesta válida, aunque yo no la haya utilizado. Por eso la marqué. Si he hecho mal marcándola, que quiten el voto los moderadores, no hay problema.

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaCano Los moderadores no tenemos ese poder. La aceptacion de una respuesta es solo postestad de quien hizo la pregunta. Es comun y pasa que muchas veces se selecciona una respuesta, y luego se cambia por otra, porque es mejor y soluciona mejor el problema, que es lo que queremos que el usuario vea. Dejando esta marcada como aceptada, cuando claramente no soluciona el problema, lo unico que logras es que se muestre primera. Claramente la respuesta aceptada tiene que solucionar el problema, y si varias personas dicen que no lo soluciona, por algo es.